# How to install texlive on ubuntu and how can I locate texlive after installation?

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu

Months ago, I successfully installed TeXLive on ubuntu 12.04. Weeks ago, I updated my system from 12.04 to 14.04 but my TeXLive stopped work. So, I tried to uninstall my TeXLive and install it again. But now I have some problems about the process.

After I install TeXLive with the command `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`, I cannot find the texlive folder in /usr/local/. But if I use the command `tex --version`, I can still see the version information of the TeXLive. So, what is wrong with the installation? Where can I find the location of the texlive/ folder?

Comment: is this helpful ?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/296681/latex-filepaths-in-ubuntu